Issue in unit test with vitest express and mongo
I use a test MongoDB database, and I have a test file for authenticationController and another for userController.
However, in some tests in these files, I insert a user with the username 'test', then delete the database after each test, yet I still get username duplication errors.
I've decided that the username should be unique in my User model, which is why I get this error, but I should not have it because it should not create multiple entries at the same time in the database.
How can I fix this or run my coverage by doing one test into another?
I tried to put this into my vitest config but it doesn't change anything:
maxConcurrency: 1
Below are 2 different tests that work alone but not in coverage:
describe("POST /api/auth/register", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await User.deleteMany();
  });

  it("should return a 201 status, create an account and store the token into the cookies", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).post("/api/auth/register").send({
      username: "test",
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      password: "test",
      confirmPassword: "test",
    });
    expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    expect(response.headers["set-cookie"][0].startsWith("__access__token=")).toBe(true);
    expect(response.body.message).toBe("Registered successfully");
    expect(response.body.user).toHaveProperty("_id", "username", "email");
    expect(response.body.password).toBeUndefined();
  });
});

describe("GET /api/users/list", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await User.deleteMany();
  });

  it("should return a 200 status and list users", async () => {
    const user = await User.create({ username: "test", email: "test@gmail.com", password: "test", role: "admin" });

    const response = await request(app)
      .get("/api/users/list")
      .set("Cookie", `__access__token=${generateAccessToken(user._id)}`);
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
    expect(response.body).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(response.body[0].username).toBe(user.username);
    expect(response.body[0].password).toBeUndefined();
  });
});

